# running ssh command with another command at the same time in a bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, background-process

I have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=0; c<=9; c++ ))
do  
    ssh -t 192.168.30.11 "tshark -i eth1 -f 'src host 192.168.31.10 and tcp' -w shared_folder/results/bbb_var_4_exp_pcaps/capture-output-$c.pcap -a duration:205" &
    python ~/shared_folder/tapas/play.py -u http://192.168.31.10/video-content/mm_videos/bbb_var_4/bbb_var_4.m3u8 -m fake -l my-exp-logs/bbb_var_4_exp_logs 
    sleep 210
done
```

I am trying to run the `ssh` command on the background do the second command `python` does not need the first command to finish. but when I add & to the end of the ssh command line it just hangs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try redirecting stdin to `/dev/null` (`ssh ... </dev/null &`).

Comment: @meuh or `ssh -fn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `-t` argument is compatible with sending the `ssh` command to the background.

### Option 1

Omit the `-t`:

```
ssh remote-machine 'command' &
```

### Option 2

Send the *remote* process to the background. You might need to [detach the remote process from stdin, stdout, stderr](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely) to allow `ssh` to return immediately:

```
ssh -t remote-machine 'command < /dev/null &> /dev/null &'
```

Comment: Could you explain the observed behaviour in the question? It seems to me that `ssh ... &` ought to start `ssh` as a background job (locally).  Your suggestion starts a background job on the remote machine. It's not clear _how_ this solves the issue (as it's not clear what the mechanism of the actual issue is).

Comment: Or `ssh -fn`, which disconnects _stdin_ etc. and runs it in the background